# How to hide/show date component on button click event in extjs?

Tags: extjs

How to hide/show date component on button click event in extjs ?
I tried it with hide() and show() method, but it doesn't work for displayField of my date componenet
Same thing happend when I tried with setvisible().

```
    // by using show() and hide()
Ext.getCmp('startDt').show(); // to show date field
Ext.getCmp('startDt').getEl().up('.x-form-composite').show(); // I removed this line cause it gives error

Ext.getCmp('startDt').hide(); // to hide date field
Ext.getCmp('startDt').getEl().up('.x-form-composite').hide(); // I removed this line cause it gives error

// by using setVisible()
Ext.getCmp('startDt').setVisible(true); // to show date field
Ext.getCmp('startDt').setVisible(false); // to hide date field
```

Comment: Please post the [code/fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home)  which you have tried so far.

Comment: show() and hide() are the proper methods. You have to have problem with object Id's and/or  scopes. What do Ext.getCmp('startDt') return?

Comment: show() and hide() works for hiding and showing components but not labels of those components